# Allow user to create only one Google Maps marker at a time

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-maps-markers

I have the following code that allows a user to click somewhere on the map and it records the GPS location of wherever they click.  It works properly on the backend but whenever the user clicks more than once it leaves multiple markers on the map.  It always keeps whatever the last location is so it works but it is somewhat confusing for the user who doesn't know what is going on on the backend.  Is there some little trick I can do to make it so that whenever the user clicks to create a new marker the old one is removed?

code:

```
    var map;
var GPSlocation;


function initialize() {
  var haightAshbury = new google.maps.LatLng(37.7699298, -93.4469157);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: haightAshbury,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };
  map =  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    addMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function addMarker(location) {
//I save the location right here
    GPSlocation = location;
    document.getElementById("GPSlocation").value = GPSlocation;
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use `setPosition` method of `google.maps.Marker` instance:

```
var map,
    GPSlocation,
    marker;  // <-- Added

// ... snip ...

function addMarker(location) {
    // ... snip ...
    if (!marker) {
        // Create the marker if it doesn't exist
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
        });
    }
    // Otherwise, simply update its location on the map.
    else { marker.setPosition(location); }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the marker a global variable by declaring it outside your function:

```
var marker;
function addMarker(location) {
    GPSlocation = location;
    document.getElementById("GPSlocation").value = GPSlocation;
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
}
```

You can also make it more efficient by only updating the location of the marker rather than creating a new object:

```
var marker;
function addMarker(location) {
    GPSlocation = location;
    document.getElementById("GPSlocation").value = GPSlocation;
    if (!marker) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });
    } else {
        marker.setPosition(location);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm I did exactly that but for some reason the map won't even render now... I'll try and debug it in the morning

Comment: @exployre you probably figured it out but there was a bug in my second example, it is corrected now.